# How can I reduce the time to run this code?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, diophantine-equations

I am trying to find the integers $ a, b, c, d \in [-15, -1] \cup [1, 15] $ so that the equation $ \left| x^2 + a x + b \right| = c x + d $ has four distinct integeral solutions different from $ 0 $.

To this end, I tried

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d];
    sol = x /. Solve[{Abs[x^2 + a x + b] == c x + d} , x, Reals];
    ClearAll[f];
    (f[{a_, b_, c_, d_}] := 
        Quiet@Check[And @@ (IntegerQ /@ #), False]) &[sol]
    poss = Select[
       Tuples[Range[-15, 
         15], {4}],  #[[1]] #[[2]] #[[3]] #[[4]] != 
          0  && #[[1]]^2 - 4 #[[2]] > 0 && #[[2]]^2 - #[[4]]^2 != 0 && 
         f[#] &];
    Take[poss, Length[poss]];
    With[{s = sol}, 
     getSolution[poss_] := Block[{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d} = poss;
       Join[poss, s]]]
    getSolution /@ poss
```

and got 426 solutions. But the time is about 15 minutes. How can I reduce the time?

Comment: $ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: Yes. I have just edited.

Comment: I wonder why I got 4284 solutions, using ~70s.

Comment: By parallelizing among 8 kernels, time consumption reduces to ~24s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["`*"]
grid = Tuples[DeleteCases[Range[-15, 15], 0], 4];

cpicked = 
  With[{IntegerQ = FractionalPart[#] == 0 &}, 
   Compile[{{m, _Integer, 1}}, 
    Module[{a = m[[1]], b = m[[2]], c = m[[3]], d = m[[4]], delta1, 
      delta2, r1, r2, r3, r4},
     If[(a + c)^2 - 4 (b + d) < 0 || (a - c)^2 - 4 (b - d) < 0, 
      0, 
      delta1 = Sqrt[(a - c)^2 - 4 (b - d)]; 
      delta2 = Sqrt[(a + c)^2 - 4 (b + d)]; 
      r1 = 1/2 (-a + c - delta1); 
      r2 = 1/2 (-a + c + delta1); 
      r3 = 1/2 (-a - c - delta2); 
      r4 = 1/2 (-a - c + delta2); 
      r1 != r2 != r3 != r4 != 0 &&
      d + c r1 >= 0 && d + c r2 >= 0 && d + c r3 >= 0 && d + c r4 >= 0 &&
     IntegerQ[r1] && IntegerQ[r2] && IntegerQ[r3] && IntegerQ[r4] // Boole]], 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
 ];

(ans = Pick[grid, cpicked @grid, 1]) // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.470872, 426}

Comment: If I want to `GCD[c,d]==1`. Where I put this conditions?

Comment: Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @matrix42 How can I use `GCD[c,d]==1`?

Answer (score 5):

First solve the equation analytically:

```
sol[a_, b_, c_, d_] = Solve[Abs[x^2 + a x + b] == c x + d, x][[All, 1, 2]] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> {1/2 (-a + c - Sqrt[-4 b + (a - c)^2 + 4 d]), 
>  1/2 (-a + c + Sqrt[-4 b + (a - c)^2 + 4 d]), 
>  1/2 (-a - c - Sqrt[(a + c)^2 - 4 (b + d)]), 
>  1/2 (-a - c + Sqrt[(a + c)^2 - 4 (b + d)])}
> ```

Then establish the grid to be searched:

```
grid = Tuples[DeleteCases[Range[-15, 15], 0], 4];
```

This sets the selection condition:

```
predicate = And[FreeQ[#, 0], And @@ (IntegerQ /@ #), DuplicateFreeQ[#]] &[sol @@ #] && And @@ Thread[#[[3]] (sol @@ #) + #[[4]] >= 0]&;
```

And finally, perform the selection:

```
(gridSelected = Parallelize[Select[grid, predicate]];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {15.3167, Null}
> ```

Check the result

```
Length[gridSelected]
RandomSample[gridSelected, 10]
sol @@@ %
```

> ```
> 426
>
> {{-10, -3, 2, 10}, {-8, 13, -1, 7}, {1, -11, -4, 13}, 
>  {12, -5, -4, 12}, {-4, -14, 1, 10}, {-12, -10, 9, 12}, 
>  {12, -4, -3, 12}, {-7, -14, 2, 8}, {-15, -12, 11, 15}, {11, -8, -7, 11}}
>
> {{-1, 13, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 4, 5}, {-8, 3, 1, 2}, {-17, 1, -7, -1}, 
>  {-3, 8, -1, 4}, {-1, 22, 1, 2}, {-16, 1, -8, -1}, {-2, 11, -1, 6}, 
>  {-1, 27, 1, 3}, {-19, 1, -3, -1}}
> ```

Comment: There are some tuples with solution is 0. Please repair.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I used `FreeQ[#, 0]` in the `predicate`, so I think there are not solutions with `0`. The `grid` does not contain `0` either, because I deleted it before building `grid`.

Comment: I tried `Length[gridSelected]
gridSelected[[;; 100]]
sol @@@ %` and tried with solution 100. 
`Reduce[Abs[x^2 - 14 x + 12] == 13 x - 14, x, Reals]`. This equation only has two solutions.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 There might exist erroneous solutions.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I added an additional condition to the `predicate` to exclude the erroneous solutions. Please see the updated contents.

Comment: I saw. Exactly is (sol @@ #) + #[[4]] > 0 not >=?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 It is right `>=` that I am using. BTW, it is `Thread[#[[3]] (sol @@ #) + #[[4]] >= 0]`.

Comment: Now has exact 426 solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84817/discussion-between-minhthien-2016-and--).